# How to add active class to nav ul li a element when it has some sub pages with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, nav

I am working on Drupal 8 website. In that i having a problem in assigning a active class to nav list elements. 
I used the following code to set the active class, it is working for the same url.
 The code look like this

```
 <nav id="getnav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="" data-drupal-link-system-path="user" href="/drupal/todo">Todo</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="" data-drupal-link-system-path="user" href="/drupal/files">Files</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="" data-drupal-link-system-path="user" href="/drupal/photos">Photos</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
</nav>
```

I used jquery function to set the active class based on the url. Using the following code.

```
 function setActive() {
     var myurl =window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
       $("#getnav ul li a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href") == '/drupal/'+myurl )
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
}
     window.onload = setActive();
```

The real problem is whenever accessing the subpages like todo/page2 the active class is gone. 
     http://localhost/drupal/todo :::is working fine but after accessing subpage like

```
 http://loclahost/drupal/todo/add
```

The class is gone.

Please give me suggestions regarding this problem.

I want to Set The Active class to all of the subpages too.after todo/*

Comment: This can be done using pure CSS. Can you add `id` or `class` to your `body` element and classes to your `nav li` elements?

Comment: Yes i used the css to body elements

Comment: You can use absolute path

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pure CSS. You need to add `class/id` to your body element and your `nav li` elements, and then you can define combinations of them in your css to be highlighted. For example, suppose this is your html:

```
< body id="todo_body">
 <nav id="getnav">
            <ul>
                <li class="todo_dropdown">
                    <a class="" data-drupal-link-system-path="user" href="/drupal/todo">Todo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="files_dropdown">
                    <a class="" data-drupal-link-system-path="user" href="/drupal/files">Files</a>
                </li>
                <li class="photos_dropdown">
</body>
                    <a class="" data-drupal-link-system-path="user" href="/drupal/photos">Photos</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Now, you can use css like given below to apply highlighting styles to your 'should be active' li element:

```
#todo_body .todo_dropdown,
#files_body .files_dropdown,
#photos_body .photos_dropdown
{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  /*Your css styles for active nav item will come here */
}
```

You can also add any styles to any elements contained in the `should be active` li element.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ul class="nav">
                    <?php
                          $page_name = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

                     ?>
                    <!-- Main menu -->
                    <li class="<?php echo ($page_name=='dashboard.php')?'current':'';?>"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>

                    <li class="submenu <?php echo ($page_name=='welcome_note.php' || $page_name=='corporate_profile.php' || $page_name=='introduction_of_the_township.php' || $page_name=='location_map.php')?'current open':'';?>">
                         <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Masters
                            <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                         </a>
                         <!-- Sub menu -->
                         <ul>
                            <li class="<?php echo ($page_name=='welcome_note.php')?'current':'';?>"><a href="welcome_note.php">Welcome Note</a></li>
                            <li class="<?php echo ($page_name=='corporate_profile.php')?'current':'';?>"><a href="corporate_profile.php">Corporate Profile</a></li>
                            <li class="<?php echo ($page_name=='introduction_of_the_township.php')?'current':'';?>"><a href="introduction_of_the_township.php">The Township</a></li>
                            <li class="<?php echo ($page_name=='location_map.php')?'current':'';?>"><a href="location_map.php">Location Map</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```